# Digital Certificate

Tags: apple-id, certificate

I have got a digital certificate from com.apple.kerberos.kdc and I would like to know if it is recognized as legal signature. I have to enroll it in a financial system and it asks details: Digital Certificate no. and the company who released it.

Please, where can I find the certificate no. and it is legally recognized?

Comment: You need a certificate from a Digital Signature provider. Your financial institute should be able to provide you with providers offering this in your country.

Comment: I didn’t tag this with the developer program, but did you perhaps enter into a legal agreement with Apple and they provided you the means to generate this certificate pair for use with Apple services instead of for a financial institution?